# Not exiting from each in Cypress

Tags: cypress

The below code works fine but but not existing the each when I return false. Is there anything am missing.

```
selectValues(dropdonwvalue, entervalue=undefined)
{  
   cy.fixture('Locators/UISelectors.json').then((selectors) => {
    let isSelected = false;   
    cy.get(selectors.dropdown).each((dropdowndiv)=> {
        if(isSelected===true) return false;
        cy.wrap(dropdowndiv).find("select").find("option").each((item, index, list)=> {
            if(item.text().includes(dropdonwvalue))
            {  
                cy.wrap(dropdowndiv).find("select").select(dropdonwvalue);
                if(entervalue!=undefined)
                   cy.wrap(dropdowndiv).find("input").type(entervalue);
                isSelected = true;
            }
            if(isSelected) return false;
        })
    }).then(()=> {
        cy.get(selectors.applyButton).click();
    })
})
```

}

Comment: What is `entervalue` and where does it come from?

Answer (score 0):

Cypress commands are asynchronous. Your outer loop is fully executed before `cy.wrap(dropdowndiv)...` will get really executed.
So you always get `isSelected` equal `false` when performing `if(isSelected===true)` check.

You can try to rewrite the inner loop using a synchronous API (jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

The `.each()` early exit needs an explicit return, you can exit the outer loop like this

```js
let isSelected = false;   
cy.get(selectors.dropdown).each((dropdowndiv)=> {

  const optionTexts = dropdowndiv.find("select")
    .find("option")
    .map((i, item) => item.innerText )

  if ([...optionTexts].includes(dropdonwvalue)) {
    cy.wrap(dropdowndiv).find('select').select(dropdonwvalue)
    isSelected = true
  }

  return !isSelected
})
```

---

It's easier to not use `each()` at all

```js
cy.get(selectors.dropdown)
  .contains('select option', dropdonwvalue)
  .parent()                       // get the dropdown
  .select(dropdonwvalue)          // select the option
```

Ok, behind the scenes Cypress is probably looking at every option, but do you notice any speed difference?